# On splitting of the conjugacy classes of $S_n$.

Tags: permutations, symmetric-groups

I was reading [this discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/404656/340973) to know whether a conjugacy class of $S_n$ splits or not when we go down to $A_n$. With this in mind when I read [this wiki](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Splitting_criterion_for_conjugacy_classes_in_the_alternating_group#Particular_cases), I am confused when looking at the table called "particular cases". Indeed if we consider the second row i.e. we consider a permutation with decomposition 1+1+1 then we have 3 1-cycles so according to the criterion it should not split (since there are 2 cycles of same length).
Also I was wondering why when the class splits, it splits only in two classes and not 3,4,5,... And why if it splits in 2 classes the respective classes cardinality is divided by 2 (it could be that more elements of the original conjugacy class go into one of the splitting class than the other no?).

Comment: Try my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3415844/a-n-and-the-conjugacy-classes/3773629#3773629

Comment: Why $|C_{S_n}(g):C_{A_n}(g)|\in\{1,2\}$?

Comment: Second isomorphism theorem as $C_H(X)=C_G(x)\cap H$.

Comment: $C_G(x)/(C_G(x)\cap H)\cong C_G(x)H/H$ but why is this of cardinality 2?

Comment: By the way, is $g^x$ a notation for $xgx^{-1}$?

Comment: $C_G(x)H$ is either $G$ or $H$ since $|G:H|=2$. And $g^x$ is either $x^{-1}gx$ or $xgx^{-1}$, depending on whom you talk to.

Comment: Oh, right! But still, concerning my question, I don't get why the permutation for which the conjugacy class "is" 1+1+1 splits. According to the criterion it should not since it has 2 (even 3) cycles of same length.

Comment: It doesn't. You aren't reading the table properly.